# React - Removing a state array item after a checkbox is unchecked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, state

So I have a state that updates when a checkbox is clicked, the item successfully is added to the state array. I'm having trouble figuring out how to remove that same item from the state array once it's clicked again/unchecked.

Relevant code from MainForm.jsx

```
 const [addon, setAddon] = useState([]);
```

Relevant code from Addons.jsx

```
function AddOns({ addon, setAddon }) {
    const checkHandler = (e) => {
        if (e.target.checked === true) {
            setAddon([
                ...addon,
                { value: e.target.value, checked: e.target.checked },
            ]);
        }

        if (e.target.checked === false) {
            //I think filtering out an item here is the way to go?
            // setAddon((addon) =>
            //   addon.filter((e) => e.target.value !== e.target.value)
            //);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
          
        console.log(addon);
    }, [addon]);

 return(
....
   <Input
                    value="Online service"
                    dataAmount="+$1/mo"
                    dataNumber="1"
                    addonDetail="Access to multiplayer games"
                    onClick={(e) => checkHandler(e)}
                />
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (e.target.checked === false) {
  const nextAddon = addon.filter(a => (a.value !== e.target.value));
  setAddon(nextAddon);
}
```